# <hr> Alignment not proper in the html layout

Tags: html, css

```css
body{
    background: #d4d4d4;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.container{
    background:#ffffff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 50%;
}



.header-1{
    background-color:#000000; 
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
    height:40px;
}

.header-1 p{

    float:right;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:white;
}

span{

    font-size:11px;
    position:relative;
    right:-145px;
    color:white;
}


.logo{
    float: left;
    width:149px;
    height:26px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.delivery{
    float:right;
    color: black;
}

.loop{
    clear:both;
    text-align: center;
}

.brand{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.brand li{
    display:inline-block;
    background: #000000;
    color:white;
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin-right:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:86px;
    height:28px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.header-banner{
    width:600px;
    height:40px;
}

.header-banner img{
    width:570px;
}

.official h1{
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.official p{
    margin-left:30px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.order-info{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.order-info li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.product-image{
    float:left;
}

.product-image img{
    margin-left:30px;
}

.product-container{
    float:right;
}

.price-list{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.price-list li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:3px;
}

.price-table{
    float:right;
}

.price-total{
    column-count: 2;
    list-style-type: none;
    column-gap:2px;
}

.line-4{
    width:100%;
    size:20;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
        <ul class="order-info">
        <li><h3>Order Info</h3><hr><p>Order#: 445501<br>
                Order Date: 26 de junio de<br> 2017</p></li>
        <li><h3>Bill To</h3><hr><p>Sergio Piana<br>
                VIA CRESPI BENIGNO<br>
                11111111111</p></li>
        <li><h3>Ship To</h3><hr><p>Sergio Piana<br>
            VIA CRESPI BENIGNO<br>
            11111111111</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <hr size="3" color="black">
      <div>
          <div class="product-image">
              <img src="http://s7d3.scene7.com/is/image/LuxotticaRetail/679420297255_shad_qt?wid=150&hei=65&fmt=jpeg&qlt=65&op_usm=2.0,0.2,0,0&op_sharpen=0">
          </div>
          <div class="price-container">
            <ul class="price-list">
                <li><h4>Model</h4><hr><p>Model:<br>
                        SKU: 679420297255<br></p></li>
                <li><h4>Quantity</h4><hr><p>1</p></li>
                <li><h4>Quantity</h4><hr><p>191.60</p></li>
                <li>Status:Cancelled</li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="price-table">
           <ul class="price-total">
               <li>Sub-total (includes VAT)</li> 
               <li>Packaging & Postage</li> 
               <li>Order Total</li>
               <li>�191.60</li>
               <li>�0.00</li>
               <li>�191.60</li>
           </ul>
          </div>
        </div> 
    <hr class="line-4">
```

I'm new to html and css. I have been trying to make an email template using html and css but it's not in the right away.The `<hr>` alignments are not proper.I have attached a screen shot as to how the look should be.

[image]

Should I have to use relative and absolute positioning or normal floats/ul and li. It would be helpful if someone gives me an insight on it. Thank You.

Comment: Can you show, how you want it to look?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the question @ashfaq.p

Comment: I can't see the screenshot

Comment: Can you please click on this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUuW8.png @FridayAmeh

Comment: can you please refer this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUuW8.png @ashfaq.p

Comment: I would point out that HTML-rich emails lag very far behind in terms of supporting CSS, especially CSS layouts.  Even if you address your concerns in a browser environment the end result (e-mail) might output VERY differently.

Comment: @SajjadTabreez please check the answer now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the `<hr>` alignment. I have also made few more changes.

```
.price-list li{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:30px;
  margin-right:3px;
  vertical-align: text-top; //This is used to align all li from top
}
```

Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/04dN4PDB3LjLHBjAOGbZ?p=preview

```css
/* Styles go here */

body{
    width:100%;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.container{
    background:#ffffff;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 50%;
}



.header-1{
    background-color:#000000; 
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
    height:40px;
}

.header-1 p{

    float:right;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:white;
}

span{

    font-size:11px;
    position:relative;
    right:-145px;
    color:white;
}


.logo{
    float: left;
    width:149px;
    height:26px;
    padding-top:10px;
}

.delivery{
    float:right;
    color: black;
}

.loop{
    clear:both;
    text-align: center;
}

.brand{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.brand li{
    display:inline-block;
    background: #000000;
    color:white;
    margin-left:-40px;
    margin-right:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    width:86px;
    height:28px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.header-banner{
    width:600px;
    height:40px;
}

.header-banner img{
    width:570px;
}

.official h1{
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.official p{
    margin-left:30px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.order-info{
    list-style-type:none;
}

.order-info li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.product-image, .price-container{
    float:left;
}

.price-container {
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.product-image {
  width: 180px;
}

.product-image img{
    margin-left:30px;
}

.product-container{
    float:right;
}

.price-list{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.price-list h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.price-list li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-right:3px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}

.price-table{
    float:right;
}

.price-total{
    column-count: 2;
    list-style-type: none;
    column-gap:2px;
}

.line-4{
    width:100%;
    size:20;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="">
        <ul class="order-info">
        <li><h3>Order Info</h3><hr><p>Order#: 445501<br>
                Order Date: 26 de junio de<br> 2017</p></li>
        <li><h3>Bill To</h3><hr><p>Sergio Piana<br>
                VIA CRESPI BENIGNO<br>
                11111111111</p></li>
        <li><h3>Ship To</h3><hr><p>Sergio Piana<br>
            VIA CRESPI BENIGNO<br>
            11111111111</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <hr size="3" color="black">
      <div>
          <div class="product-image">
              <img src="http://s7d3.scene7.com/is/image/LuxotticaRetail/679420297255_shad_qt?wid=150&hei=65&fmt=jpeg&qlt=65&op_usm=2.0,0.2,0,0&op_sharpen=0">
          </div>
          <div class="price-container">
            <ul class="price-list">
                <li><h4>Model</h4><hr><p>Model:<br>
                        SKU: 679420297255<br></p></li>
                <li><h4>Quantity</h4><hr><p>1</p></li>
                <li><h4>Quantity</h4><hr><p>191.60</p></li>
                <br>
                <li>Status:Cancelled</li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div class="price-table">
           <ul class="price-total">
               <li>Sub-total (includes VAT)</li> 
               <li>Packaging & Postage</li> 
               <li style='border-top:1px solid black;margin-top:20px;padding-top:18px'>Order Total</li>
               <li>�191.60</li>
               <li >�0.00</li>
               <li style='border-top:1px solid black;margin-top:18px;padding-top: 18px'>�191.60</li>
           </ul>
          </div>
        </div> 
    <hr class="line-4">
  </body>

</html>
```